# PDO: Mapping multi tables (select with join) in multi classes

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

With a SELECT statment with a single table

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id = :id
```

I can easly mapping the output in the Customer class

```
class Customer 
{
    private $id;
    private $name;

    private Company;
   // etc...
}
```

in this way

```
// ...
return $stmt->fetchALL(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Customer");
```

but in the query with two or more table

```
SELECT * FROM customer AS cu JOIN company AS co ON cu.company_id = co.id WHERE cu.id = :id

class Company
{
    private $id;
    private $name;

   // etc...
}
```

How could I populate `Customer` class with `Company` data using  `$stmt->fetchALL(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Customer")` ?

Comment: Just do with two queries and assign a company to customer's object.

Comment: But that is the simpler scenario... With 100 customers, I should to make 100 queries to get the companies? And if the select has three tables?

Comment: Use cache for this scenario. It will be faster than additional query and much faster than join. Alternative way is to use FETCH_FUNC http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php where you can map properties manually.

Comment: @AndrejLudinovskov for "use cache" you mean don't re-execute a query, if the query has been already executed...or is there a better way? Actually, I will execute two queries to get all user's companies and all user's customers and then I'll bind companies with their customers.